# AWS EMR spark: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=livy, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:hdfsadmingroup:drwxr-xr-x

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

Getting following error while executing df.write.mode("append") on kinesis df in AWS EMR Spark PySpark notebook. Where do we add these permissions?

An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o179.start.
: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=livy, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:hdfsadmingroup:drwxr-xr-x
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:351)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:251)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:189)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1756)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1740)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1699)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:60)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3015)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1132)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:662)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:507)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1034)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1003)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:931)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1926)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2854)

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:88)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2507)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2480)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1243)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1240)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:1257)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:1232)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:2269)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.<init>(StreamExecution.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.<init>(MicroBatchExecution.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.createQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:322)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:297)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```